# Probability that the sum of any subset of i.i.d. random variables exceeds a certain threshold

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume I have given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ i.i.d. discrete, positive random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Let's say for simplicity that the $X_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$ are binomial distributed with $N$ trials and success probability $p$. For two other integers $s,t \in \mathbb{N}$, I am interested in the probability
$$\mathrm{Pr} \left\{ \exists \mathcal{S} \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} : |\mathcal{S}| = s \land \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} X_i \geq t \right\},$$

i.e., the probability of the event that there exist $s$ variables $X_i$ such that their sum is at least $t$. In particular I am interested, whether it is possible to obtain a tighter upper bound apart from the union bound

$$ \mathrm{Pr} \left\{ \exists \mathcal{S} \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\} : |\mathcal{S}| = s \land \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} X_i \geq t \right\} \leq \binom{n}{s} \mathrm{Pr}\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^s X_i \geq t \right\}, $$

which is also relatively easy to evaluate. Note that for the example of binomial distributed $X_i$, the sum of $s$ $X_i$'s is also binomial distributed with $sN$ trials and thus easy to evaluate.

It seems to me that the union bound is not really tight as many of the subsets $\mathcal{S}$ have significant overlap and thus are very dependent. Do you have any ideas on how to obtain a tighter lower bound that is relatively easy to evaluate? I would be glad about any ideas or hints towards related literature.

Comment: Would $s$ be large enough that you could approximate your sums by Gaussians? They would then jointly have a multinormal distribution with a covariance matrix that should be feasible to calculate.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. The regime I am interested in would be large $n$, and $s = \sigma n$, $t = \tau n$ for some constants $\sigma,\tau$. So the idea would be to introduce $s!$ random variables $Y_{\mathcal{S}} = \sum_{i\in\mathcal{S}} X_i$, approximate each of them via Gaussian approximation and compute their covariance?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. Now on second thought it appears not that easy, because (1) the covariance matrix will contain different values for different-sized intersections $S \cap S'$ and (2) even if you have the multinormal, you then need to integrate over a funny-shaped domain. It might be doable but not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

For exact computation we can try a recurrent formula. Let $S_n$ denote the maximum value of the set of subset-sums of a given outcome of $n$ random variables. We have:

$\scriptstyle{Pr(S_{1} = k) = 
\begin{cases} \begin{array}
\;0 &  \text{when } k < 0\\
Pr(X_{1} = k) & \text{when } k > 0\\
\end{array}
\end{cases}}$

$\scriptstyle{Pr(S_n= k) =\\ = \begin{cases} \begin{array}
\;0 &  \text{when } k< 0 \\ Pr(S_{n-1}= k)Pr(X_{n} \leq 0) +  \int^{k}_{0}Pr(S_{n-1} = t)  Pr(X_{n} = k-t) dt & \text{when } k>0 \end{array} \end{cases}}$

This is made to include the null-subset as having sum $0$ for convenience. The issue is computing closed forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe it's possible to derive closed-form expressions (approximations) from the recursion using complex analysis then, since you derived linear recursions (for the case of discrete RVs, the integrals become simple sums). This is a nice direction - I'll think about it.